# What is the difference between "el rincón" and "la esquina"?

Tags: vocabulario, sinónimos

From the RAE definitions for el rincón and la esquina (in regards to corners), the former seems to refer specifically to an interior corner, whereas the latter seems to refer more to an exterior corner. Is that a correct interpretation of when to choose one over another? I see esquina listed as a synonym for rincón, but not the other way around.

Also, I would use esquina over rincón to reference the corner of a street, correct? As in, "the pharmacy is on the corner?" For example, in English, I wouldn't say "street corner". WordReference uses the example: Gira a la derecha al llegar a la esquina.

rincón: 1. m. Ángulo entrante que se forma en el encuentro de dos paredes o de dos superficies.

Sin.: ángulo, esquina, recodo, cantón, canto, sucucho.

esquina: 1. f. Arista, parte exterior del lugar en que convergen dos lados de una cosa, especialmente las paredes de un edificio.

Sin.: arista, ángulo, cantón, cantillo, canto, vértice, chaflán, esquinazo, borde, punta.

Comment: I think your understanding iss correct

Comment: Yes, rincon, a corner of the room, also a niche. esquina=a street corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal pregunta fue respondida por [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/rincon-y-esquina-2312/) en su momento:

> rincón y esquina
>
> P: ¿Estoy en lo cierto cuando, al discutir sobre este tema con mis amigos, les >digo que un rincón es por dentro y una esquina es por fuera?
>
> R: Sí, está en lo cierto. La confusión tal vez se deba a que en inglés solo hay una palabra («corner») para ambos, pero en español se distinguen.

Rincón admite otra acepción más que no fue mencionada y es la de ‘lugar oculto o retirado’, como si fuera algo que abarque mayor extensión que una esquina. Hay un montón de lugares que comienzan con el nombre ‘Rincón’, v.g., *Rincón de los Sauces* y sin embargo más bien pocos que lleven la palabra ‘esquina’ (pero existen también).

Y en el caso del fútbol, por favor no uses ninguno de los dos términos. Las personas normales dirían que un ‘defensor mandó la pelota al *córner*’, no al rincón ni a la esquina.

Comment: "Las personas normales dirían ..." no es un poco fuerte, implicando que son "anormales" los que no siguen ese uso?

Comment: Además, he oido con frecuencia "saque de esquina" y similares para la reanudación del juego tras un _corner_

Comment: Según mi esposo, ex-jugador profisional, se dice tanto córner como esquina. Y  claro, eso de la personas normales, es un poco pasarse. no? :)

Comment: @Sofronias No. ‘tiro de esquina’ y ‘saque de esquina’ son usados en el periodismo, claro que sí. PERO, en una conversación normal y general se le dice *córner*.

Comment: cc @Lambie Pero de acuerdo, a ustedes que les gusta custionarme todo, muy bien. Si tan normal es eso, entonces extendamos su argumento ¿Cómo le dirían por ejemplo en el jockey? Si hay dos equipos que juegan un partido y hay un córner corto para alguno, ¿qué dicen, hay una ‘esquina corta’? Además, yo dije ‘mandar la pelota (rechazar el balón) al córner’. ‘Mandar la pelota a la esquina’ significaría literalmente afuera del estadio, a la calle. Infórmense un poquito más, y feliz navidad.

Comment: Sus dos afirmaciones de que "Las personas normales dirían ..." y "tiro de esquina y saque de esquina son usados en el periodismo" parece implicar que los periodistas no son personas normales !!!

Comment: ¿Cómo dirían en por ejemplo en el jockey [sic]?. Suponiendo que se refiera al **-hockey_** (https://dle.rae.es/hockey) debo indicarle que a) no es pertinente cómo se diga en otro deporte y b) lo desconozco, porque es un deporte que no sigo.

Comment: "Mandar la pelota a la esquina’ significaría literalmente afuera del estadio, a la calle.2 - No, mandar la pelota a la esquina del terreno de juego, que tiene esquinas. Ademñás de que existe algo llamado "uso metafórico".

Comment: @Sofronias andá a la esquina a ver si llueve, dale? Muy bien, en tu idioma artificial, típico de quien se pasa de mirar la tele en vez de prestar atención a los términos que se usan en conversaciones normales (córner mucho más versátil y usado que ‘esquina’, tanto para la zona como para la acción de sacar desde esa zona), quedaría: *El defensa ha rechazado el balón a la esquina*. Pero, mierda que hay que tener más polenta que [Sergio Ramos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIA-4MU1eq0) para hacer algo así! Sea como fuere, Felices Fiestas mi ñeri, que disfrutes mandando balones a la ‘esquina’.

Comment: Posdata: No me hagas caso, hacé caso a lo que [las estadísticas tienen para mostrar](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=corner%2Cc%C3%B3rner%2Ctiro+de+esquina%2Csaque+de+esquina&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=3). Saludos

Comment: @tac: Tentado estoy de repetir, con el Pichi, eso de "Anda, y que te ondulen", pero la política de Stack Exchanges es "BE NICE" y me comprometí a eso.

Comment: *córner* o esquina son palabras de fútbol usada en español. Nada tiene que ver con jockey [hockey, no?]. No hay que confundir los diferentes deportes. Te dije y te repito: Mi esposo fue jugador profisional de fútbol en España. Sabe más sobre el tema que tú y yo.

Comment: @Lambie ‘Mi esposo fue jugador profisional de fútbol en España’. Sos consciente de que no hay ninguna forma de probarlo? Yo entonces soy el presidente de la Academia Argentina de Letras. Ya dije que ‘tiro/saque de esquina’ es válido para la acción de sacar. Pero a la zona del campo se le dice ‘córner’, sino guglealo a ver que es lo que más aparece. Si querés meterte en la discusión, traé argumentos sólidos (v.g. estadísticas, DATOS), y no argumentos como ‘yo soy X’, ‘mi esposo es Y’ o ‘conozco a alguien que es Z’. Eso no contribuye en absoluto. Un saludo.

Comment: Whatever you say. Corner and esquina is not about where you kick the ball, it's about a player who takes the ball there to kick it after a foul. Sure, I can't prove what I said about my husband, but what would I gain from lying?? tiro/saque de esquina no es sacar la pelota, es meterla en el juego con un tiro por un jugador.

Comment: @Lambie A mí no me hables así. Con todo respeto, es notorio que no tenés idea de lo que estás hablando. ‘Sacar la pelota’ y ‘hacer un tiro’ es exactamente lo mismo. Y no hay ningún jugador que se llame ‘córner’, ni es lo mismo ‘foul’ que ‘córner’. Porque estabas hablando del **fútbol americano**, pero yo hablé de **fútbol** lo cual son dos deportes bien distintos. Al final estabas hablando de otro deporte, qué lástima. Siga participando.

Comment: NO EXISTE corner en  fútbol americano. Para de hacer comentarios personales.  Se le da al jugador del equipo opuesto saque de esquina o córner cuanda hay falta, que se dice foul en inglés.

Comment: Análisis y evaluación del lanzamiento [tiro o saque[ de esquina (**córner**) en el fútbol de alto nivel
Analysis and evaluation of the corner kick in soccer at the highest level
J.. Sánchez-Floresa, J.M.. García-Mansoa, J.M.. Martín-Gonzálezb, E.. Ramos-Verdea, E.. Arriaza-Ardilesc, M.E.. Da Silva-Grigolettod Oh mira, todos hispano hablantes! https://www.elsevier.es/es-revista-revista-andaluza-medicina-del-deporte-284-articulo-analisis-evaluacion-del-lanzamiento-esquina-X1888754612850245 Revista andaluza de medicina del deporte

Comment: "es notorio que no tenés idea de lo que estás hablando". tsk, tsk, tsk Sabes traducir tsk?

Comment: @Lambie Estás equivocada. La equivalencia correcta es: Análisis y evaluación del [lanzamiento tiro o saque de esquina] = [córner]... Además de que un ejemplo difícilmente venza a la estadística que mostré de Ngrams. Además de que en el fútbol (que es el soccer en tu idioma) no se saca de esquina cuando hay un foul.

Comment: You just repeated what I said. "La equivalencia correcta es:"??? I just had the square bracket in the wrong place. A corner is taken by the opposing team when a player kicks the ball over the end line.  a saque de esquina or córner in Spanish is corner in English. You're right about the foul. There is no foul when a corner is taken. And again: **stop making personal comments**. I am getting really fed up with them.